# How to harden security on services in ubuntu?

Tags: security, services, lynis

I was auditing my computer (with lynis) and then I saw that I have bad security on almost all of my services when I run "sudo systemd-analyze security SERVICE". I was wondering if there was a way to harden them, how do I do it? Also is there a way to auto harden them?

Thanks to everyone who helps :)!

Comment: Ubuntu is intended to be secure-by-default; it should not require any additional "hardening" for most users. If you discover a real vulnerability or insecure setting among the Ubuntu defaults, please file a bug report so it can be fixed.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182494/how-to-address-results-of-systemd-analyze-security